# How to know the debug console is enabled on ipad and iPhone in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, user-interface

I am trying to set marginLeft for a div when the page orient, I have calculated some values get the positions and set, But when I enable the debug console on iPad the positions becoming changed! Please help me.